# ordered same not returning result in comparison of dates Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, compare, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I run this I get a result when I use OrderedDescending or OrderedAscending but not OrderedSame, even though the dates for newyear are the same.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

    let christmas = dateFormatter.dateFromString("12/25/2015")

    let newyear = dateFormatter.dateFromString("11/29/2015")

    let update = dateFormatter.dateFromString("02/01/2016")

    let date2 = NSDate()

    if date2.compare(newyear!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message:
            "Happy New Year. ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if date2.compare(christmas!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message:
            "Merry Christmas.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }De
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your first issue is your date format. You need "MM/dd/yyyy". Also, `NSDate()` returns the current date (including time), so it is not exactly the same as a date from format "MM/dd/yyyy" which does not include the given time, even if the day of the year is the same. So you should use `NSCalendar`'s date comparison function using the unit granularity .Day, rather than NSDate's compare function.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

let newyear = dateFormatter.dateFromString("11/29/2015")
let date2 = NSDate() // Currently 11/29/2015

let order = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(newyear!, toDate: date2,
    toUnitGranularity: .Day)

if order == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
        print("same")
}
```